# MySQL jdbc connection in Eclipse Keppler Tomcat 7

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc, tomcat7

I have installed a fresh Eclipse but forgot to back up my tomcat Context and Server xmls (if that is even the problem).
Now I can't get the MySQL db connection up.

here are the relevant parts of the files:

EDIT:
server.xml has no context elements

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/ListenB" 
    debug="5" reloadable="true" crossContext="false">

  <Resource name="jdbc/LDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
     maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
     username="student" password="password" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teacher" />
</Context>
```

and my web.xml has this block:

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/LDB</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I have the following driver
/ListenB/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar
and it's also on the build path:

[image]

When I go to create a db through Eclipse's Database Development tab, I get this:
[image]

But the test ping fails.
There's a page and a half of why, but it just has useful statements like:
"The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."

Let me know if you need the rest of it.

I love Tomcat, but the explanations on the page are as clear as... well, something not very clear. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
By popular demand, the ping error message:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2395)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2316)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:298)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:81)
at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1129)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:358)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2489)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2334)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:308)
... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling fresh versions of the jdk and jre and following all the steps of this tutorial solved my problem. I couldn't say for sure what fixed it, although I realized I hadn't actually copied the new jdbc connector to the tomcat lib directory. That could have been it.

Anyway, a fairly complete and thorough tutorial and I recommend it, if only to ensure that you have all of the obvious bases covered, before you go on to debug:

[Configuring Eclipse, MySQL and Apache Tomcat in Windows 7](http://asisonline.blogspot.jp/2012/08/configuring-eclipse-mysql-and-apache.html)

Note that it says Windows 7, but these steps worked for me on XP.

Thanks again portTech.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be declaring your resource only in the context.xml file .

Look for  line starting "Caused By" It should give you more clear exaplanation. Most probably you have:
1) Mysql server not up. 
2) Port number configured wrongly in the connect url.

Also , do upload the error trace. It will help if both of my hypothesis proves to be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the context from the server.xml, but after a clean and restart, the same issue is there. See if the error trace above sheds any light on the issue...